# Meteor Android uploading Data URI to Amazon S3

Tags: cordova, meteor, camera, android-camera

Why am I unable to upload the result of taking an image with mdg:camera? I have read through countless AWS S3 upload forums and Meteor camera UI forums but cannot find the correct way to upload a DATA URI file to S3. I've tried converting it to a Blob, File, DATA URL, DATA URI, Canvas, Form, all to no avail.

If I simply upload a file it works perfectly, but starting with a DATA URI file it doesn't. No errors though, it simply just doesn't do anything.

```
Meteor.CameraUI.getPicture({
    quality: 50
}, function(error, data){
    S3.upload({
        files: data,
        path: '/'
       }, function(e, r){
        console.log(r);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert it to a blob, and then add a name attribute. These uploads are very fickle, and will often upload just an empty file.

I use this utility to convert the URI to a blob:

https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob

and a bit of code like this:

```
var blob = dataURLtoBlob(dataUrl);
blob.name = "filename.png";
```

You should be able to send the blob to S3 from there.

Comment: There are plenty of answers like this one all over stackoverflow to similar questions. My problem is specifically with using a DATA URI that is returned from MDG:Camera package for Meteor. Amazon S3 won't seem to accept the "Blob" as a "File". I've tried using Canvas to convert it to blob but it just uploads empty file every time.